# Why I got double click in ng-template?

Tags: angular

I have the following temaplte:

```
<table class="table table-borderless tablelist-custom-style">
 <tbody>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="ordersTableHeadTemplate"></ng-container>
</tbody>
</table>

<ng-template #ordersTableHeadTemplate>
     <tr>
     <th class="align-bottom">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" (click)="test()">
     </th>
     </tr>
</ng-template>
```

When I do a `(click)="test()"` I got two clicks instead one:

[image]

Method is:

```
 test() {
     console.log('1');
 }
```

Comment: Probably ng-template such works, try to pull out `test()` outside ng-temaplate

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: In stack it work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xp1vps

Comment: That means that you forgot to mention something :)

Comment: It helped me `  e.preventDefault();` somewhere exist native click JS seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description) is a structural directive which is called with asterix. Try to call it accordingly:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ordersTableHeadTemplate"></ng-container>
```

Comment: The same result, I dont get why it called twice: 2,3,6,8

Comment: Structural directive can be called without asterix

Comment: if move `(click)="test()"` to `th` it works without duplicates, maybe my custom checkbox has own click somewhere? So I try to add prevent

Comment: Yes, it helped: `  e.preventDefault();`